# Expand grid in R with unlist and apply

Tags: r, datagrid, combinations, permutation

I am looking to use R's `expand.grid` to comprehensively enumerate and investigate options for hierarchical clustering analysis. I have a final function `acc` which will take a matrix and analyse it for performance measures like accuracy, precision, F1 etc., returning a named list (with accuracy, F1, etc.): the ultimate output I'm looking for is a table where all the hyperparameter combinations are listed and, in columns next to them, the different performance measures (accuracy, F1,...).

The table of combinations can be set up for example with

```
hyperparams =  expand.grid(meths=c("ward.D","ward.D2","single","complete","average","mcquitty","median","centroid"), dists=c("euclidean", "maximum", "manhattan", "canberra", "binary","minkowski"))
```

Next we would compare to known labels and get the accuracy, wrapping in a number of functions, which I've tried to omit for brevity (like `cutree`):

```
t1 = table(df$Group, hclust(dist(df[-1],method="euclidean"), method="complete"))
Res1 = acc(t1)
```

The goal is to vary the `method` argument for `dist` across those listed in my `dists`, and the `method` argument for `hclust` across those listed in my `meths`. 
In the final line, recall that I've written `acc`, which will take a matrix and output a named list of accuracy, precision, F1,... which I'd like each on a column of a final table, whose rows are the hyperparameter combinations in `hyperparams`.

Now, my first issue is, I'm not sure how to use `unlist` in a way that will cover all the options above. I'm pretty sure it's the right function but just not sure how to do it. And I also want to create the table **without** a for-loop, i.e. using apply or something like that (I guess applying along the rows of `hyperparams`?...), since I know such solutions are generally better in R.

As suggested, the final desired output would be, effectively, `hyperparams` but as a data-frame with additional columns, the third column containing accuracy, fourth containing precision, etc (the measures listed out in my function `acc`). Can anyone inform me how to get there?

If you want something to play with for `acc`, we could use

```
first = sum(x)
second = sum(x^2)
return(list(First=first,Second=second))
```

and the final output table would be the two hyperparameter columns followed by a column for `First` (sum of elements in the final confusion matrix, for the hyperparameter combo corresponding to that row) and `Second` (sum of elements^2 in the final confusion matrix). Just a hypothetical example in case you like to work with given functions.

I'd really prefer solutions in base R! (Or dplyr if absolutely necessary)

**Edit:** OK, many people are asking for a `df`. Let's use `iris`, but of course if we want output we can't avoid some of the intermediate functions, like `cutree`.

Now with `iris`, you could run

```
contingtab1 = table(iris$Species, cutree(hclust(dist(iris[,1:4],method="euclidean"),method="complete"),3))
```

That gives a contingency table. Passing this into `acc` would give one row of the desired output (the row corresponding to `euclidean` and `complete`. The desired output would then look like `hyperparams` with each of the two current columns followed by (say) two more columns, one for each of my two performance measures in `acc`.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of `df` and the `acc` function?

Comment: How do you plan to quantify the similarity to the known labels if the arbitrary integer assigned to each cluster may change from iteration to iteration?

Comment: @Dij don't worry, I've taken account of that by diagonal maximisation. @Ian Campbell, a dummy example for ```acc``` is provided; for ```df``` you could literally use any data-frame, as long as it has a factor variable (here called ```Group```) which is removed for performing ```hclust``` but used for comparison.

Comment: I've added an example for ```df```

Answer (score 2):

One approach might be `map2` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
map2(hyperparams$meths, hyperparams$dists,
     ~ acc(hclust(dist(df[-1],method = .x), method = .y)))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `Map` in `base R`

```
Map(function(x, y) acc(hclust(dist(df[-1],method = x), method = y),
           hyperparams[[1]], hyperparams[[2]])
```

Comment: Thank you, this goes a long way to a solution. But it seems to lose the headings, which are somewhat important to me... (that's to say, the final output is a list which can be coerced into a table that has all the numerical info I wanted: but the rows are not labelled anymore. It's like only having the columns First and Second from my ```acc``` function above, not the hyperparameter labels anymore.)

Comment: @MobeusZoom would you mind providing an example 'df'

Comment: I've edited my post. Have a look, hopefully that's enough?

Comment: @MobeusZoom so your 'df' is `iris`?

Comment: @MobeusZoom not able to reproduce

Comment: We can consider ```iris```, sure. As I said, the method will work for any dataframe. Do you mean the code ```contingtab1 = table(iris$Species, cutree(hclust(dist(iris[,1:4],method="euclidean"),method="complete"),3))``` doesn't run for you? ```iris``` is preloaded in base-R so I can't imagine why...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213458/discussion-between-mobeus-zoom-and-akrun).