# Map over dataset names in R

Tags: r, combinations, apply

I am trying to analyse the `iris` data-frame with clustering analysis. I was provided here a way to use `Map` in R to map the data onto sets of hyperparameter combinations listed by `expand.grid` and collect all results in one table.

I would now like to do this for modified versions of the data-frame at the same time. So for example:

```
acc <- function(x){
  first = sum(x)
  second = sum(x^2)
  return(list(First=first,Second=second))
}
tests <- expand.grid(Clustering_Algorithm=c("ward.D","ward.D2","single","complete","average","mcquitty","median","centroid"),
                     DS=c("iris0","iris1","iris2"))
iris0 <- iris
iris1 <- cbind(log(iris[,1:4]),iris[5])
iris2 <- cbind(sqrt(iris[,1:4]),iris[5])
Table <- Map(function(x, ds){acc(table(ds$Species, cutree(hclust(dist(ds.[,1:4]),method=x),3)))},tests[[1]], tests[[2]])
```

This fails to run for me with the error "Error in ds$Species : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors". I've tried writing `as.character(tests[[2]])` instead which had the same error message. I've even tried options like `ds %>% .[,"Species"])` and `ds %>% .[,1:4]`, in which case I get a different error message: " Error in .[, "Species"] : incorrect number of dimensions".

Any idea how to fix it?

Edit:

Just tried to use `lapply` over the list `DS` and after putting rest of the above in a function, and that gave me the exact same error message.

Comment: You are calling `ds.` while it is `ds` and also it is a string  (convertedd to character)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that 'ds' is a string, we need to get the value with `mget` or `get`

```
Map(function(x, ds){
    acc(table(get(ds)$Species, cutree(hclust(dist(get(ds)[,1:4]),method=x),3)))
          }, as.character(tests[[1]]), as.character(tests[[2]]))
```

---

It can be made more compact if we use `mget`

```
Map(function(x, ds) {
      acc(table(ds$Species, cutree(hclust(dist(ds[, 1:4]), method = x), 3)))
   }, as.character(tests[[1]]), mget(as.character(tests[[2]])))
#$ward.D
#$ward.D$First
#[1] 150

#$ward.D$Second
#[1] 6492


#$ward.D2
#$ward.D2$First
#[1] 150

#$ward.D2$Second
#[1] 6352
#....
```

---

If we want to change the 'tests' with a string having subset of column index, instead of `mget` use `eval(parse`

```
tests <- tests[1:4, ] # subset the first four rows
tests$DS <- c("iris0[,1:4]","iris1[,1:3]","iris2[,2:4]", "iris0[, 1:3]")

Map(function(x, ds) {
   ds1 <- eval(parse(text = ds))
   sp <- get(sub("\\s*\\[.*", "", ds))$Species
  acc(table(sp, cutree(hclust(dist(ds1), method = x), 3))) 
   }, as.character(tests[[1]]), as.character(tests[[2]]))
```

Comment: Thank you, of course it's been helpful for me (as you can see)-- so I upvoted it. But I'm still hoping for one that can retain the row-names from hyperparams and col-names from acc without having to reinsert later. I thought it would use unlist() and then apply over the rows of hyperparams, or something like that, since I think that unlist at least is common in conjunction with expand.grid, and apply is a better alternative to for-loops.

Comment: (For others, this is in reference to my earlier question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61687341/expand-grid-in-r-with-unlist-and-apply.)

Comment: @MobeusZoom if you can update the expected format in your other post, it would help

Comment: I was wondering, do you know a method that would work if you had datasets of different sizes, that you have to index differently? So, say, you could supply ```DS=c("iris0[,1:4]","iris1[,1:3]","iris2[,2:4]")``` and it would still work? I don't mind rewriting ```DS``` or any other part in any way that would make this work. Currently I get ```Error in get(data) : object 'iris[,1:3]' not found```

Comment: @MobeusZoom you meant iris0, iris1, iris2 etc are having different number of columns right

Comment: @MobeusZoom I assume that your `iris0 <- iris[, 1:4]; iris1 <- iris[, 1:3], iris2 <- iris[, 2:4]` when you do `get("iris0")` it is checking for that object created in the global env.  the `"iris[, 1:3]"` is not an object created in the env

Comment: @MobeusZoom If the 'DS' column is having elements like "iris0[, 1:4]", you can do `eval(parse(text = "iris0[, 1:4]"))`

Comment: @MobeusZoom you may need `Map(function(x, ds) {
       ds1 <- eval(parse(text = ds));
       acc(table(iris$Species, cutree(hclust(dist(ds1), method = x), 3)))
    }, as.character(tests[[1]]), as.character(tests[[2]]))` here, the `iris$Species` is the common one.  (not tested)

Comment: Thanks!! The only issue with it is that we would also want the ```get(ds)$Species```, not just ```iris$Species```. I think combined with your solution above, we might just use ```strsplit```? It might seem clumsy but we could write ```DS=c("iris0 [,1:4]","iris1 [,1:3]","iris2 [,2:4]")``` first with spaces, then ```strsplit("iris0 [,1:4]"," ")``` for example gives a list of ```"iris0"``` and ```"[,1:4]"```. Can we combine that with your method to solve the general case, assuming we are free to write DS in this form?

Comment: @MobeusZoom. You could use `sub` i.e. `get(sub("\\s*\\[.*", "", ds))$Species`

Comment: @MobeusZoom updated.  if the column 'Species' is different in each dataset, you may want to have another vector of that also as argument to `Map` and then use `get(sub("\\s*\\[.*", "", ds))[[nm1]]` where `function(x, ds, nm1)` and the argument to `Map` would be `as.character(tests[[1]]), as.character(tests[[2]]), vecofspeciescolnames)`

Comment: Thank you!! And you even thought of a further generalisation which I'm sure would also be helpful. Now, basically, the results of clustering from different datasets can be stored in a vectorized way. Mostly thanks to you :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213815/discussion-between-mobeus-zoom-and-akrun).